# iOS Social framework and encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, frameworks, social-framework

I'm writing an app where you can type some text. I'd like to add the capability to post on Facebook and Twitter via the Social framework. So no log-in and so on, only the SLComposerViewController object.

Because inside the Social framework, as I understood, there are APIs to deal with accounts and requests, I think Social framework contains some encryption...

So, if I include Social framework in my app should I need export compliance approval?

I remark that my app only share a typed text, not does account operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not 100% believe anyone who answers this question, unless they are a lawyer. But...

No you won't have to get export compliance.

If you want further confirmation I suggest you either ask a lawyer or ask Apple.